# how to add Filter menu and Color menu tools to Toolbox in GIMP

Tags: filter, colors, toolbox

I am using the same tools on GIMP a lot, but they are not part of the toolbox, mostly tools from the filter or color menu (e.g. enhance, exposure,...). They are not in the list that I can select in the preferences/toolbox, so is there another way to attach these tools to the toolbox?

thanks,
Sina

tried to find them in the list of the toolbox tools that can optionally be shown in the preferences/toolbox list, but they do not appear there...